# Why does CMake 3.16 looks for boost_program_options<version> instead of libboost_program_options<version>?

Tags: windows, boost, cmake

I'm using CMake 3.16 on Windows to generate a visual studio 2019 solution that depends upon boost::program_options. [This](https://github.com/trprice/EveSDEImporter) is the link to the code on Github. I have built [Boost 1.72](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_72_0.html) with the following command:

`.\b2 install --reconfigure --prefix=F:\dev_programs\boost --build-type=complete`

The libraries that were generated are as follows (limited to the program_options output because that's what CMake will be looking for):

[image]

The find_package command in the CMakeLists.txt file is as follows:

`find_package(Boost 1.72.0 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)`

As seen in the output below, when cmake looks for the program_options library it looks for `boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_72` instead of `libboost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib` that was generated by the boost build. Copying the genereated libraries and removing the `lib` prefix makes this works successfully. It doesn't, however, feel like I should have to do that.

I have not found any answer for why this happens. Does anybody else have any ideas?

```
[ F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2044 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt;boost_program_options-mt-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-mt-x64;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
[ F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:649 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = "F:\dev_programs\boost/lib"
[ F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:651 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "F:\dev_programs\boost/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
[ F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2099 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64-1_72;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
[ F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:649 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = "F:\dev_programs\boost/lib"
[ F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:651 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "F:\dev_programs\boost/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
CMake Error at F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options) (found suitable version
  "1.72.0", minimum required is "1.72.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  F:/dev_programs/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2165 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
```

Comment: You probably need to set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `ON` for search Boost **static** libraries. Exactly static libraries have `lib` suffix.

Comment: On Windows, .lib files are used to link against even if DLLs are used. They're used (in C/C++ anyway) to contain the declarations of the functions so that the compiler knows where they are.

That's not actually the problem. The problem is the *prefix* to the file name. libboost_... vs boost_...

Comment: Tsyvarev is correct, you've built the static libraries of Boost (see the Boost naming conventions [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming)), you need to either build the shared libraries (`link=shared runtime-link=shared`) or set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to `ON`.

Comment: I will give building boost that way another try. I recall the build with those options not producing any output. I’ll update the question with the results of that if there are problems.

Comment: In my first comment I meant `lib` **prefix**, not *suffix*. Not sure why I have written so...

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm testing building boost as @squareskittles suggested and we'll see if it builds ok for me on a different computer.

Comment: Alright, it looks like my build of boost on the computer that I initially experienced this on was dirty. From a fresh build of boost I do get the shared libraries without the lib prefix generated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the comments from @Tsyvarev and @squareskittles were correct.

I needed to build Boost with `link=shared` and `runtime-link=shared` supplied to `b2.exe`. I had tried that but, having now tried it on a computer with a fresh boost download, it worked magically. Given that I will clean my environment and try again.

Comment: You might consider not building Boost at all and use the binaries provided by the maintainers from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/ and for the latest version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.72.0/ The installation files contain static libs and DLLs as well.

Comment: That's fair. However, it looks like they only provide the binaries for Windows. I plan on building my project on MacOS as well. I figure that building it gives me the opportunity to see another code base and build system as well. The more I see, the more I learn